# How to fix baked particle simulation at certain frame so you can use that static state in subsequent animation?

Tags: animation, particles

I want to stop particle simulation at frame 153(for example), then rotate the camera to show the whole picture of the static mode of the particles.

It's like the scene in Matrix, Trinity jumps and kicks but you stop her in the middle of the air and give a rotating shot around her.

I want to stop the flying particles at a certain frame, I do not need them moving again, I just need them all to stop at a certain frame.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Timestep under under Physics > Integration > Timestep

1. Go to the frame before you want the particles to pause, in this case frame 152
2. Mouse over the Timestep and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe
3. Advance 1 frame forward, onto frame 153
4. Change the Timestep value to 0
5. Mouse over the Timestep and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert another keyframe

That's it! The particle simulation will now be paused.

[image]

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much, this is exactly I was looking for!